# Has_one Association breaking in Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have a nested form using the cocoon gem that gests 5 classes deep.  They are all belongs_to and has_many except one that is the 2nd to most nested class with a has_one and belongs_to association.  Whenever I edit it, it gets deleted and recreates an instance (not what I want) any ideas?

```
class FirmwaresController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @firmwares = Firmware.all
    end

    def new
        @firmware = Firmware.new
    end

    def edit
        @firmware = Firmware.find(params[:id])
    end
end


class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu_item
  has_many :selections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :dependencies
  attr_accessible :kind, :name, :placement, :selections_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :selections, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  validates_presence_of :kind
end

class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu
  belongs_to :dependency
  has_one :setting, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessible :dependency_id, :menu_for, :name, :placement, :setting_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :setting, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  validates_presence_of :name

end
```

_menu_items.html.haml

```
.row-fluid
        .input-prepend      
            = f.input :name, label: "Menu Item Name"
        .input-append
            = f.input :placement, label: "Order in Menu (X.Y)", as: :string
    = f.simple_fields_for :setting do |settings_form|
        = render 'setting_fields', f: settings_form
    %p  
        = link_to_add_association "Has Setting?", f, :setting, class: "btn btn-primary btn-small add_setting_link"
        = link_to_remove_association 'Remove Menu Item', f, class: "btn btn-danger btn-small remove_menu_item"
```

_setting_fields.html.haml

```
.row-fluid
    .input-prepend
        = f.input :kind, label: "Type", collection: setting_kinds, input_html: {class: "setting_type"}
    .input-append
        = link_to_remove_association 'Remove Setting', f, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-small remove_setting_link'
.setting_selection{style: "display: none;"}
    = f.simple_fields_for :selections do |selections_form|
        = render 'selection_fields', f: selections_form
    %p= link_to_add_association 'Add Selection Option', f, :selections, class: "btn btn-primary btn-small"
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume the `has_one` association you're referring to is the `has_one :setting` in `MenuItem`. If so, you might try adding `update_only: true` to your `accepts_nested_attributes_for :setting` options. [From the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) (emphasis mine):

> By default the :update_only option is `false` and the nested attributes are used to update the existing record only if they include the record's `:id` value. **Otherwise a new record will be instantiated and used to replace the existing one.** However if the :update_only option is `true`, the nested attributes are used to update the record’s attributes always, regardless of whether the `:id` is present.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but this could help some people:

The reason the association was always recreated for me, was that I had forgotten to include `:id` in the permitted parameters of `phone_number_attributes`! If you forget to do that, rails wont get the id and will recreate a new record to replace the old one.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :avatar,
    :remove_avatar,
    { id_photo_attributes: [:photo, :remove_photo] },
    { phone_number_attributes: [:id, :phone_number] } # dont forget :id here!
  )
end
```